File Upload Issues in Android Studio -- Button Doesn't Open Files
I have a sorting app that can take a picture live or upload one from their phone. The camera function works just fine (minus an image rotation sometimes)--the user can take a picture with the camera and run it through the model. However, the upload button doesn't do anything when clicked. It shows that the button is clicked, but nothing happens when it is. There are no errors thrown and the debugger is clean. I'm still very new to Android Studio in general, but have some python experience.
I've tried checking permissions (Both read, manage, and write to external storage are added to the manifest, along with ACCESS_WIFI_STATE), and I've tried rewriting the file path, double checking the button titles to make sure it's all spelled correctly. Here is the code snippet that isn't working:

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize UI elements
        result = findViewById(R.id.result);
        confidence = findViewById(R.id.confidence);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        picture = findViewById(R.id.button);
        uploadButton = findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);

        // Ensure necessary permissions
        checkAndRequestPermissions();

        // Set listeners for the buttons
        picture.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Launch camera
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);
            } else {
                // Request camera permission
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 100);
            }
        });

        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Open gallery
                Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, 2);
            } else {
                // Request storage permission
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 101);
            }
        });
    }


    private void checkAndRequestPermissions() {
        // Check and request camera and external storage permissions
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 100);
        }

        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 101);
        }
    }
    private String saveImageToTemporaryFile(Bitmap image) {
        String filePath = null;
        try {
            File tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp_image", ".jpg", getCacheDir());
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            filePath = tempFile.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return filePath;
    }

    private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
        String filePath;
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            filePath = uri.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            filePath = cursor.getString(idx);
            cursor.close();
        }
        return filePath;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            String imagePath = saveImageToTemporaryFile(image);
            processImage(image, imagePath);


        } else if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            // Handle gallery result
            try {
                InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                String imagePath = getRealPathFromURI(data.getData());
                processImage(image, imagePath);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }



First, delete getRealPathFromURI(), as it is rather wrong. Second, you do not need READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE for ACTION_PICK and you cannot hold that permission on the newest versions of Android.

What would be a better way to get the image path? Or is it not needed here? I originally did not have the storage permissions, but added them to see if that was a potential error. I will take them out and see if it helps fix the issue.

"What would be a better way to get the image path?" -- there does not have to be a path. ACTION_PICK and similar actions are not limited to the filesystem, let alone files that you can access. "Or is it not needed here?" -- I do not know what processImage() does. Since you already have the image itself through the Uri, I do not know what value the "path" is supposed to be providing to you.
